# Socket.io - Close Server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io server in my app, listening on port 5759.

At some point in my code I need to shutdown the server **SO IT IS NOT LISTENING ANYMORE**.

How Can I accomplish this?

Socket.io is not listening on an http server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a server :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('socket_is_connected','You are connected!');
});
```

To stop recieving incoming connections

```
io.server.close();
```

NOTE: This will not close existing connections, which will wait for timeout before they are closed. To close them immediately , first make a list of connected sockets

```
var socketlist = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socketlist.push(socket);
    socket.emit('socket_is_connected','You are connected!');
    socket.on('close', function () {
      console.log('socket closed');
      socketlist.splice(socketlist.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
});
```

Then close all existing connections

```
socketlist.forEach(function(socket) {
  socket.destroy();
});
```

Logic picked up from here : [How do I shutdown a Node.js http(s) server immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately)

Comment: use `io.close()` to stop receiving incoming connections. API was updated somewhere ~2015 Q2

Comment: `io.close()` doesn't close existing connections though

Answer (score 17):

This api has changed again in socket.io v1.1.x
it is now:

```
io.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The API has changed. To stop receiving incoming connections you should run:

```
io.httpServer.close();
```