# How I can CLOSE socket.io server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is my code:

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

var sockets = [];

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   console.log('client connecting');
   sockets.push(socket);
});

server.listen(5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    io.server.close(); // same as server.close()
    sockets.forEach(function(socket){
        socket.disconnect(true);
    });
},5000);
```

After 5 sec timeout I still receive connections... How to stop it? I want to just KILL it forever!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.io - Close Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000120/socket-io-close-server)

Comment: socket.disconnect(true);

Comment: It does not work - still io clients can connect...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js) (see `disconnect(close)` method), it requires `true` parameter for closing underlying connection.

```
socket.disconnect(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
socket.destroy();
```

You might be receiving connections because of reconnection attempts made by clients.

Comment: socket does not have method destroy(). Yes clients are reconnecting.