# Force close all connections in a node.js http server

Tags: node.js, http

I have an http server created using:

`var server = http.createServer()`

I want to shut down the server. Presumably I'd do this by calling:

`server.close()`

However, this only prevents the server from receiving any new http connections. It does not close any that are still open. `http.close()` takes a callback, and that callback does not get executed until all open connections have actually disconnected. Is there a way to force close everything?

The root of the problem for me is that I have Mocha tests that start up an http server in their setup (`beforeEach()`) and then shut it down in their teardown (`afterEach()`). But since just calling `server.close()` won't fully shut things down, the subsequent `http.createServer()` often results in an `EADDRINUSE` error. Waiting for `close()` to finish also isn't an option, since open connections might take a really long time to time out.

I need some way to force-close connections. I'm able to do this client-side, but forcing all of my test connections to close, but I'd rather do it server-side, i.e. to just tell the http server to hard-close all sockets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I shutdown a Node.js http(s) server immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to

1. subscribe to the `connection` event of the server and add opened sockets to an array
2. keep track of the open sockets by subscribing to their `close` event and removing the closed ones from your array
3. call `destroy` on all of the remaining open sockets when you need to terminate the server

You also have the chance to run the server in a child process and exit that process when you need.

Answer (score 9):

For reference for others who stumble accross this question, the https://github.com/isaacs/server-destroy library provides an easy way to `destroy()` a server (using the approach described by Ege).

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's maintained anymore

Comment: How much maintenance do you need for 19 lines of code?

Comment: @MaMa more than you'd expect. E.g. that code doesn't work for HTTPS servers, doesn't play nicely with promises, and doesn't close up connections cleanly. The world move forwards - nowadays https://www.npmjs.com/package/stoppable is a better option imo.

Comment: another project in that direction is http-terminator: https://github.com/gajus/http-terminator

Answer (score 7):

I usually use something similar to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

/* a dummy route */
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

/* handle SIGTERM and SIGINT (ctrl-c) nicely */
process.once('SIGTERM', end);
process.once('SIGINT', end);


var listener = server.listen(8000, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var host = listener.address().address;
    var port = listener.address().port;

    console.log('Server listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});


var lastSocketKey = 0;
var socketMap = {};
listener.on('connection', function(socket) {
    /* generate a new, unique socket-key */
    var socketKey = ++lastSocketKey;
    /* add socket when it is connected */
    socketMap[socketKey] = socket;
    socket.on('close', function() {
        /* remove socket when it is closed */
        delete socketMap[socketKey];
    });
});

function end() {
    /* loop through all sockets and destroy them */
    Object.keys(socketMap).forEach(function(socketKey){
        socketMap[socketKey].destroy();
    });

    /* after all the sockets are destroyed, we may close the server! */
    listener.close(function(err){
        if(err) throw err();

        console.log('Server stopped');
        /* exit gracefully */
        process.exit(0);
    });
}
```

it's like Ege Özcan says, simply collect the sockets on the connection event, and when closing the server, destroy them.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a [closeAllConnections()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/http.html#servercloseallconnections) method in v18.2.0

Answer (score 5):

I've rewriten original answers using modern JS:

```
const server1 = http.createServer(/*....*/);
const server1Sockets = new Set();

server1.on("connection", socket => {
    server1Sockets.add(socket);
    socket.on("close", () => {
        server1Sockets.delete(socket);
    });
});

function destroySockets(sockets) {
    for (const socket of sockets.values()) {
        socket.destroy();
    }
}

destroySockets(server1Sockets);
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach comes from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately/14636625#14636625) and it basically does what @Ege Özcan said.

The only addition is that I set a route to switch off my server because node wasn't getting the signals from my terminal (`'SIGTERM'` and `'SIGINT'`).

Well, node was getting the signals from my terminal when doing `node whatever.js` but when delegating that task to a script (like the `'start'` script in package.json --> `npm start`) it failed to be switched off by `Ctrl+C`, so this approach worked for me.

Please note I am under **Cygwin** and for me killing a server before this meant to close the terminal and reopen it again.

Also note that I am using **express** for the routing stuff.

```
var http=require('http');
var express= require('express');

var app= express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('I am alive but if you want to kill me just go to <a href="/exit">/exit</a>');
});

app.get('/exit', killserver);

var server =http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
  /*console.log(process);*/
});


// Maintain a hash of all connected sockets
var sockets = {}, nextSocketId = 0;
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // Add a newly connected socket
  var socketId = nextSocketId++;
  sockets[socketId] = socket;
  console.log('socket', socketId, 'opened');

  // Remove the socket when it closes
  socket.on('close', function () {
    console.log('socket', socketId, 'closed');
    delete sockets[socketId];
  });

  // Extend socket lifetime for demo purposes
  socket.setTimeout(4000);
});


// close the server and destroy all the open sockets
function killserver() {
    console.log("U killed me but I'll take my revenge soon!!");
  // Close the server
  server.close(function () { console.log('Server closed!'); });
  // Destroy all open sockets
  for (var socketId in sockets) {
    console.log('socket', socketId, 'destroyed');
    sockets[socketId].destroy();
  }
};
```