# Express server doesn't close

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm creating an Express server with reloadable endpoints.
To make this possible I created an endpoint for such a purpose.

But when I call `server.close()` on the Express's HTTP server it still continues listening, while the `server.listening` says otherwise, it still is.

Here is a simplified version of my script (*Not working fully, but you get the gist*):

```
class simpleServer {
    constructor() {
         let express = require('express');
         this.app = express();
         this.app.get('/reload', this.reload);
         this.server = this.app.listen(3000);
    }

    reload(req, res) {
         console.log('Closing server');             

         this.server.close(function() {
             console.log('Closed server');
         });
         
         // Re-init & stuff

         res.json({
             message: 'Reloaded'
         });
    }
}

let server = new simpleServer();
```

When I call the endpoint, the server will output 'Closing server', but the 'Closed server' takes a long time to be called (5 minutes). And when I reload the page, it still works, while the `server.listening` is equal to `false`.

I'm using Node.js version **6.0.0** with Express version **4.14.0**.

---

Some updates:

I fixed the issue by calling `req.destroy()` after sending the response, does this have any side-effects tho?

A cleaner fix would be keeping a record of current connections and closing those in the reload function instead of closing them instantly. This will probably be less heavy if you have a higher load.

Answer (score 11):

When you call `.close()`, it only stops accepting *new* connections, it does not terminate existing connections.

The reason it may take some time to actually close is if there are existing connections that have set `Connection: keep-alive` in case of more requests.

Comment: So the connection stays open, even after I send my response?

Comment: Yes, if `Connection: keep-alive` was requested by the client. It's an HTTP/1.1 feature to reduce the overhead of creating and tearing down a connection for each HTTP request.

Comment: @lorenzo373 Related existing question on [force-closing connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately). Joshua Wise has an interesting answer on dealing with keep-alive requests gracefully

Answer (score -2):

You can use process.exit().

Or you can try

```
this.server.close(function() {
   console.log('Closed server');
})();
```

Comment: That is not what I am trying to achieve.