# setInterval continues even after nodejs process/server exits

Tags: node.js, express, timer, process, setinterval

I have a route in my expressjs which calls some logic on an interval:

```js
export const get = (req, res) => {
  const { ids } = req.query;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    let id = ids.pop()
    console.log("On id #:", id)
    // do some stuff with the id
    if (!ids.length) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)
  interval.unref();
  res.json();
};
```

So if you hit the route that calls this function, code runs every 1 second, and prints the console statement.  This is all within an express server.  If the process runs to completion, great.  However, I notice that even if I `ctrl c` out of the server's running process before the interval loop is done, the terminal continues printing the id every 1 second, until its done.

I thought the `.unref()` method is supposed to prevent this, but it has no effect.  I also tried this:

```js
["exit", "uncaughtException", "SIGINT", "SIGTERM"]
  .forEach(signal => {
    process.on(signal, () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    });
  });
```

This also seems to have no effect.  **How can I make sure that any running intervals are stopped and cleared when I shut down my express server?**

Maybe my issue has something to do with some convoluted logic for the setup and cleanup of my server.  For reference:

```js
import express from "express";
import { setRoutes } from "./routes";

let app = express();

const server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log(` Server is now running on port : ${8080}`);
});

app = setRoutes(app);

function stop() {
  // Run some code to clean things up before server exits or restarts
  server.on("close", function () {
    console.log("⬇ Shutting down server");
    process.exit();
  });
  server.close();
}

process.on("SIGINT", stop);
process.on("SIGTERM", stop);
process.on("SIGQUIT", stop);

process.once("SIGUSR2", function () {
  // Run some code to do a different kind of cleanup on nodemon restart:
  process.kill(process.pid, "SIGUSR2");
});
```

Comment: `process.exit()` will stop your process and not wait for any timers.  There may be some data that was already in stdout that gets flushed when the process exits, but the timers don't keep running.  `timer.unref()` just tells nodejs not to wait for the timer before exiting naturally.  It doesn't have anything to do with when things exit if you call `process.exit()`.  Now, if you have child processes somewhere, that could be a different issue.

Comment: `server.close()` will wait for existing server requests that are in process to finish before actually closing so perhaps that is something in play here.

Comment: `server.close` will wait for existing open sockets to close. https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode

Comment: Thanks to @jfriend00, I looked into [How do I shutdown a Node.js http(s) server immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626636/how-do-i-shutdown-a-node-js-https-server-immediately), and implementing that logic seems to have fixed the issue.